# Filter out vertical lanes in Freeform Data driven dashboard. (VTB)

Tags: dashboard, servicenow

I have created a Virtual Task Board in Service Now for displaying Incidents, tasks and change request under one roof.(All are part of task table)

I have used task table as primary table for this data driven VTB. However, there are around 100 sub types of task table due to which there 100 vertical lanes created for the board.

I applied filter on vertical lanes from the configuration. However, the filter is getting applied only for my account. When I shared the board with others, they are unable to see filtered board. All they see is 100 vertical lanes and filter needs to be applied for each and every used individually.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

"I have created a Virtual Task Board in Service Now for displaying Incidents, tasks and change request under one roof.(All are part of task table)"

I would love to know how you did this!  I am a SN newbie and have the options for "freeform" and "flexible" board.  In "freeform," I don't see an option to edit/create any filters at all, and with the "flexible" board, it appears I can only select one table (sctask OR inc etc).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).